# Is it okay to use an overloaded operator to implement another operator overload?

Tags: c++, oop, coding-style, operator-overloading

For instance if I have overloaded a + operator

```
myClass & operator + (const myClass & rhs)
```

and also overloaded = operator

```
myClass & operator = (const myClass & rhs)
```

both operators are working fine. Can I use this overloaded operator in my += operator overload?

```
myClass & operator += (const myClass & rhs){

*this = *this + progA;

return *this;

}
```

The above code is working okay. I just want to know if this is good code writing practice or I should re-use the code from the two previous implementations for the += operator overload.

Comment: It's actually common practice. A great rule of thumb is to *avoid* duplicating code when you can. Though in my experience you are more likely to see `operator+` implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

Comment: Is isn't actually spelled out  but everything you want know is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you. Can you elaborate on your last statement?

Comment: You'd see `operator@` implemented by using `operator@=` because it can be more efficient. It's often possible for the `@=` to be more efficient than the plain `@`

Comment: @Mykel Notice that `*this + progA` will have to create a temporary instance of `myClass` which shouldn't be strictly necessary for implementing `operator+=`. If you implement `operator+=` directly and instead change `operator+` to refer to `operator+=` (make a copy of `*this` and call `operator+=` on that copy, which you return) you can get away with a more efficient implementation.

Comment: @Justin Thank you for the explanation. But if you implement an @= Operator before the @ operator, doesn't that mean you would have to reuse some code to implement the @ operator? going against the rule of thumb of duplicating code?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Wow. That's brilliant. Thank you. New skill to add to my tool. Thanks once again

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that. However, it is more common to implement `operator+` using  `operator+=` instead of the other way around.

```
myClass & operator += (const myClass & rhs) { ... )

// Return by value.
// const member function.
myClass operator + (const myClass & rhs) const
{
    myClass ret = *this; // Uses copy constructor, not assignment.
    return ret += rhs;
}
```

The interface

```
myClass & operator + (const myClass & rhs);
```

is not idiomatic since you cannot do the equivalent of

```
int a = 10 + 20;
```

Using

```
MyClass a = MyClass(args...) + MyClass(args...);
```

won't work since the first object in RHS is a temporary object.