# Operator "+" overload returns array of zeroes

Tags: c++

I have a simple operator + overload method for a class Macierz which is supposed to get the 2d matrix variable from the object, and sum all of this matrix variable with the same field of another Macierz object.

```
Macierz & operator + (Macierz &f) {
    Macierz newM;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) 
            newM.macierz[i][j] = macierz[i][j] + f.macierz[i][j];


    return newM;
}
```

The calculating works fine. Displaying the `newM` variable produces a correct value, however when I try to use it like this:

```
float y[3][3] = { {1.00f, 2.00f, 3.00f}, { 4.00f, 5.00f, 6.00f }, { 7.00f, 8.00f, 9.00f } };
Macierz m5(y); //fill m5 array with values from above
    Macierz m2(2.00f); //fill m2 entirely with 2.00f values

    cout << m2 + m5;
```

The result is an array of zeroes.

How could this happen? The `macierz` variable is a simple `float[3][3]` field.

Any help would be amazing

Comment: You + operator returns a reference to a local variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Answer (score 5):

> The result is an array of zeroes.

You are returning a reference to a function local variable. The reference becomes a dangling reference as soon as the function returns. As a consequence, your program has undefined behavior.

Change the function to return by value instead.

```
// Remove the reference type specifier
//     |
//     v 
Macierz operator + (Macierz &f) {
    Macierz newM;
    ...
    return newM;
}
```

I suggest couple of further refinements to the function.

1. Change it to a `const` member function.
2. Change the argument type to a `const&`.

With those changes, you can use the function using `const` objects too.

```
Macierz operator + (Macierz const& f) const {
    Macierz newM;
    ...
    return newM;
}
```

A related post: [Is it okay to use an overloaded operator to implement another operator overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657351/is-it-okay-to-use-an-overloaded-operator-to-implement-another-operator-overload).

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: This is a whole lotta unnecessary overhead. The temporary here is not needed. Just add to the original matrix and return the reference to *this* at the end

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, it is idiomatic to return an object by value from the binary `+` operator function. Think of `int a = 10 + 20;` if the `operator+` function returns a reference, you can't use that.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername -- maybe, but that's a different operation than the original. The original doesn't modify the object that `+` is called on; your version does. In fact, your version would typically be named `operator+=`, and would be used to implement `operator+(const Macierz&, const Macierz&)`.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, I meant what Pete Becker wrote below.